# Panorama 360 degrees viewer with thumbnail slider to click and select dynamic images for previewing in 360 degrees panaromic viewer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, panoramas

I have used http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html for panoramic view. But i need to place a slider. By which when I click an image from the slider, the panorama image must be replaced with the current selected image and the panorama 360 degree must apply to the image. 
I can't show the website where I found such example, as there is no direct link. Below is an image to show example
[image]

As seen in the image. There is a thumbnail image from which images are selected dynamically on click. Then the selected image is displayed in the preview which is a panorama slider. Is there any slider for this functionality. Please post the link.

Comment: There is no slider precisely for this purpose But I have used it in a property detail page you can see it here https://duperty.com/realestate/property/property_detail/20 using dynamic images from database